# AngularJS apply directive after load data and do that on each select tag

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that should aplly on each 'select' tag, but because it parse the select data it should be done **after** the data loded.

The following code i wrote work just on the last select item:

```
    myApp.directive('optionsClass', function ($parse) {
    return {
        require: 'select',
        link: function ($scope, elem, attrs, ngSelect) {

            $scope.updateLang = function () {
                 // Here i perform data parsing
            }
         }
     };
   });
```

controller:

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.loadData = function () {
            $http({
                url: 'x',
                method: 'POST',
                data: { data: $scope.data}
            }).then(function(response) {
                  $scope.updateLang();
             }
        });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following -

```
function loadData(){
  $scope.loading = true; // additional variable to keep track if data is loading or not
  someService.getData()
  .then(function(success){
     // populate success.data in your model property
  })
  .finally(function(){ $scope.loading = false; // loading is complete)
}
```

And in your template you can wrap the whole thing inside a `div` with an ng-if-

```
<div ng-if="!loading">
  // your code here
</here>
```

in this way, while `loading` is true the inner html of the above `div` will not be compiled. And when the `loading` is false, then it is for sure that your data is loaded and then your inner html code will be compiled.

Comment: I've tried that but it's look like the directive not been recognize (i've got "$scope.updateLang is not a function")